# Node js ORM supporting Schema changes

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, bookshelf.js

I was considering Sequelize as nodejs orm, but ran into issue while modifying the schema it does not support new columns directly.  [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708620/sequelize-changing-model-schema-on-production) thread states "migrations" framework as workaround.  This seems to be a development overhead especially after first cycle of changes you will end up either deleting the test data or will have to create migration for each new column change. does node-orm or bookshelf have the same problem? I am using postgres database.

Answer (score 1):

Using sequelize's migrations, you do not need to create a new migration for each column change as you can include many changes within a migration.

I use fixtures to load my test data so that migrations do not affect my data.

I haven't tried node-orm nor bookshelf, however I have no reason yet to stop using sequelize!

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at fixtures